# How to create a custom page width using the Dart PDF package?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I have created a PDF file using the Flutter package `pdf 1.3.24` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) but I can't figure out how to create a document with a custom page width. The document is a receipt and will be printed on a thermal printer.

Here is how I set the page format:

```
pdf.addPage(MultiPage(

    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.standard.copyWith(marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),

      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

      header: (Context context) {
...
```

PdfPageFormat will only accept a range of predefined page sizes which don't include a thermal printer 80 mm roll and continuous page length.

Answer (score 6):

```
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat(8 * PdfPageFormat.cm, 20 * PdfPageFormat.cm, marginAll: 0.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
```

would give you a 8x20 cm page with 5mm margin

Comment: What about a variable page length such as a thermal printer receipt?

Comment: Nothing as yet, your answer is a huge advance as it is.